# psql -o not what I expected (how to output db response to an output file)

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a PostgreSQL database from the command line (i.e. using psql).

There are some errors in my SQL statements and I want to find out where the errors are occuring (too many objects to fill the screen buffer - so I need to save thios to file)

I have tried just about everything, from using the -o option, the -L option and using tee - I still cant capture the information that scrolls past on the screen.

How do I log this?

This is what I have tried so far:

- psql -U -o dbcreate.log -f file.sql
- psql -U -L dbcreate.log -f file.sql
- psql -U -a -f file.sql | tee dbcreate.log

NONE of which results in the data flashing accross the screen being logged to file - how do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `pg_dump`? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tag/pg-dump-command

Comment: `-U` is for specifying a username, what purpose does it serve on your command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr. On Un*x and Linux:

```
psql ... 2>error.log
```

or both stdout and stderr:

```
psql ... &>error.log
```

On the other hand if you like to investigate the errors one by one:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 ...
```

A helpful article about executing SQL scripts with psql - [here](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-scripts-with-psql.html).

Comment: Looks like just what I need. Regarding your other question (-U option on the command line) - Is there a way where I can run these command (say from a bash script), totally automated - i.e. without it prompting me for a password?

Comment: Actually, I saw that in the postgre docs (before I asked you). problem is I can't find any example of how to use it. Unless 'using it' simply involves entering details of the user in the .pgpass file?